# Prove a simple inequality (triangle inequality on a norm)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2\geq 0$.

Prove that

$\left(|a_1+a_2|^2+|b_1+b_2|^2\right)^{1/2}\leq\left(a_1^2+b_1^2\right)^{1/2}+\left(a_2^2+b_2^2\right)^{1/2}$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Definitions and stuff http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Norm and http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Euclidean_norm bam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$(a_1 + a_2)^2 + (b_1 + b_2)^2 = (a_1^2 + b_1^2) + (a_2^2 + b_2^2) + 2(a_1a_2 + b_1 b_2),$$

and

\begin{align}(a_1 a_2 + b_1 b_2)^2 &= (a_1^2 + b_1^2)(a_2^2 + b_2^2) - a_1^2 b_2^2 - a_2^2 b_1^2 + 2a_1b_1a_2b_2\\
&= (a_1^2 + b_1^2)(a_2^2 + b_2^2) - (a_1b_2 - a_2b_1)^2\\
&\le (a_1^2 + b_1^2)(a_2^2 + b_2^2),
\end{align}

thus

\begin{align}(a_1 + a_2)^2 + (b_1 + b_2)^2 &\le (a_1^2 + b_1^2) + (a_2^2 + b_2^2) + 2\sqrt{(a_1^2 + b_1^2)(a_2^2 + b_2^2)}\\
&\le \left((a_1^2 + b_1^2)^{1/2} + (a_2^2 + b_2^2)^{1/2}\right)^2.
\end{align}

Taking square roots results in

$$[(a_1 + a_2)^2 + (b_1 + b_2)^2]^{1/2} \le (a_1^2 + b_1^2)^{1/2} + (a_2^2 + b_2^2)^{1/2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

A proof without words:

[image: A proof without words]

$$\phantom{}$$

Comment: really nice !!  thanks for share it !!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: First apply CS inequality:$\sqrt{\dfrac{a_1^2+b_1^2}{(a_1+a_2)^2+(b_1+b_2)^2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{a_2^2+b_2^2}{(a_1+a_2)^2+(b_1+b_2)^2}} \geq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{a_1^2+b_1^2}{a_1^2+b_1^2+a_2^2+b_2^2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{a_2^2+b_2^2}{a_1^2+b_1^2+a_2^2+b_2^2}}\right)\geq 1.$.

To prove the above inequality: consider the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-x}\right)$ on $(0,1)$, and show that $f$ attains a minimum at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ which is $1$.

Comment: For those unsure, norm: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Norm this norm is http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Euclidean_norm and the proof there (as here) uses the CS inequality, meaning Cauchy-Schwarz referring to http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Cauchy-Schwarz_inequality